# bash command wont run in python3

Tags: python, bash

I made a python3 script and i need to run a bash command to make it work. i have tried `os.system` and `subprocess` but neither of them fully work to run the whole command, but when i run the command by itself in the terminal then it works perfect. what am i doing wrong?

```
os.system("fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 -D 1 picture.jpg &> /dev/null")
os.system("echo -e "From: abc@gmail.com\nTo: abc1@gmail.com\nSubject: package for ryan\n\n"package for ryan|uuenview -a -bo picture.jpg|sendmail -t")
```

or

```
subprocess.run("fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 -D 1 picture.jpg &> /dev/null")
subprocess.run("echo -e "From: abc@gmail.com\nTo: abc1@gmail.com\nSubject: package for ryan\n\n"package for ryan|uuenview -a -bo picture.jpg|sendmail -t")
```

This is supposed to take a picture and email it to me. With `os.command` it gives an error "the recipient has not been specified "(even though it works perfect in terminal by itself) and with `subprocess` it doesnt run anything

Comment: `&>` is a bash-only feature. `os.system()` and `subprocess.run(..., shell=True)` use `sh`, not `bash`. Write it the long way, `>/dev/null 2>&1` and you'll be compatible with both shells.

Comment: Did you notice that your second attempted call to os.system() (echo...) is syntactically flawed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Best Practice: Completely Replacing the Shell with Python

The *best* approach is to not use a shell at all.

```
subprocess.run([
    'fswebcam',
    '-r', '640x480',
    '--jpeg', '85',
    '-D', '1',
    'picture.jpg'],
  stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Doing this with a pipeline is more complicated; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline, and many duplicates already on this site.

---

#### Second Choice: Using sh-compatible syntax

`echo` is poorly defined by the POSIX sh standard (the [standard document itself](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) advises against using it, and also fully disallows `-e`), so the reliable thing to do is to use `printf` instead.

Passing the text to be sent as a literal command-line argument (`$1`) gets us out of the business of figuring out how to escape it for the shell. (The preceding `'_'` is to fill in `$0`).

```
subprocess.run("fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85 -D 1 picture.jpg >/dev/null 2>&1",
               shell=True)

string_to_send = '''From: abc@gmail.com
To: abc1@gmail.com
Subject: package for ryan

package for ryan
'''
p = subprocess.run(
  [r'''printf '%s\n' "$1" | uuenview -a -bo picture.jpg | sendmail -t''',
   "_", string_to_send],
  shell=True)
```

Comment: Is specifying `stdout/stderr` necessary with `capture_output=False`?

Comment: @kojiro, you get file descriptors inherited from the parent process if you don't override them. If the OP wants stderr to be thrown away completely instead of printed to the terminal (which is unwise, but seems to be what they want), it needs to be specified.

Comment: @ryanpositiveguy, I'm glad to hear it! If your question is solved, please consider clicking the checkbox by the answer.